# unable to open .jar executable file from another java project

Tags: java

There is an application inside which there are three buttons , when user clicks on the 1st the notepad exe file opens 
but when user clicks on the second the java .jar file doesnot open . can someone please help 
following is the code i am posting

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       //InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
   // BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
  try {
    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();

    // Use command "notepad.exe" and open the file.
    p.command("java.exe", "C:\\Users\\zareeba\\Desktop\\KictCHE_UAT");
    p.start();}
  catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
       // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `-jar`:

```
p.command("java.exe", "-jar", "C:\\Users\\zareeba\\Desktop\\KictCHE_UAT");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this by adding `-jar` also as argument

```
p.command("java.exe", "-jar", "C:\\Users\\zareeba\\Desktop\\KictCHE_UAT.jar");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-jar` flag. You need to add the `-jar` flag like this:

```
p.command("java.exe", "-jar", "C:\\Users\\zareeba\\Desktop\\KictCHE_UAT");
```

Comment: the screen is blank; neither showing error nor opening exe file

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to run exe file:

```
 try {
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Test.jar");
     Process process = pb.start();    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e="+e);
    }
```

Comment: the screen is blank . it is neither opening the exe file nor displaying any error

Comment: I check the code and run .jar file use this code. Please check your .jar file path

Comment: yes it worked . thank you actually it is a netbeans project so .exe has to be change with .jar